# Logback configuration without explicit appender defining

Tags: logback

The following Logback configuration, one of the loggers explicitly defines it's appender, another one not:

```
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="60 seconds">

<appender name="AMAZING_APPENDER" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>XXX</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<logger name="org.springframework">
    <level value="ERROR" />
</logger>

<logger name="com.company" additivity="false">
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="AMAZING_APPENDER"/>
</logger>

</configuration>
```

What appender would the **logger without the explicit appender specification** would use, if any at all?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By "logger without the explicit specification" I think you are referring to this: `<logger name="org.springframework">`.

If so, then there is no appender available for that logger and any log events emitted by classes in the `org.springframework` (regardless of the log level) will be ignored.

If you tweak your logback.xml slightly to add this: `<configuration debug="true">` you'll see a WARN event of this nature ...

> No appenders present in context [default] for logger [...]

... emitted when a class in the `org.springframework` emits a log event at ERROR level.

If you want events from the `org.springframework` namespace (or more generally, from any namespace other than `com.company`) to be logged then you should add a `<root>` configuration. For example:

```
<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="AMAZING_APPENDER"/>
</root>
```

If you add a root and point it at `AMAZING_APPENDER` then you should probably set `additive="false"` on `logger name="com.company"` otherwise anything logged from the `com.company` namespace will be logged twice. So, perhaps your desired configuration will be:

```
<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="STANDARD_APPENDER"/>
</root>
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. I have edited the question to reflect it. So in order to have a configuration that will catch an emitted log event, I need to add a <root> configuration?

Comment: @Stas yes, you'll need a `<root>` configuration. I have updated the answer to include this.

Comment: <configuration debug="true"> this is gold